# How can I add spacing between navigation bar and UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I would like to add a progress bar between navigation bar and UISearchBar. May I know how can I implement this? Please help. Thank you.

[image]

**Here is my current code in Cell.m**

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect barFrame = CGRectInset(self.searchBar.frame, 10.0f, 10.0f);
    self.searchBar.frame = barFrame;
}
```

**Here is my current code in ViewController.m** 
Did not reflect in this code after edited. `_searchBar=[[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kScreenWidth, 24)];`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    _valueProgress = [[LDProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,DCNaviH, ScreenW, 10.0f)];
    _valueProgress.type = LDProgressSolid;
    _valueProgress.color = ThemeRedColor;
    _valueProgress.progress = 0.40;
    _valueProgress.flat = @YES;
    _valueProgress.showText = @NO;
    [self.view addSubview:_valueProgress];
}
- (UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    if (!_searchBar) {
        _searchBar=[[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kScreenWidth, 24)];
        [_searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_searchBar_bgImage"]];
                                                                                                 }];
    }
    return _searchBar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few simple options for you depending on your apps UX. I think the best solution for you based on how you explained your issue would be to include the progress bar to your view and make sure it's above the other views while positioning it below the navigation bar.

```
_valueProgress = [[LDProgressView alloc] init];
_valueProgress.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_valueProgress.type = LDProgressSolid;
_valueProgress.color = ThemeRedColor;
_valueProgress.progress = 0.40;
_valueProgress.flat = @YES;
_valueProgress.showText = @NO;
[self.view addSubview:_valueProgress];
[_valueProgress.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor].isActive = YES;
[_valueProgress.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.trailingAnchor].isActive = YES;
[_valueProgress.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:10.0f].isActive = YES;

if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    [_valueProgress.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor].isActive = YES;
} else {
    [_valueProgress.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor].isActive = YES;
}
```

And if the search bar has been added above the progress bar, you can always call `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_valueProgress]` afterwards.